# They're ready for you, doctor/Doctor

Tags: capitalization

I know that "Doctor" is capitalized when their name follows, like Dr. Watson/Doctor Watson, but what about when addressing a doctor without mentioning their name?

They're ready for you now, doctor.

vs

They're ready for you now, Doctor.

Comment: I don't know that there's a rule about this, but I would capitalise a title if it is being used as a substitute for the person's name.

Comment: On the other hand (*contra* Kate), if it’s used as a simple noun, leave it uncapitalised.

Comment: I read the example as using ***Doctor*** as a title, substituting for the name, and thus would be with Kate Bunting in capitalizing. However, in the sentence *The doctor will see you now.*, I would *not* capitalize, as it is not being used as a title, but as a simple noun, as per Lawrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the name, the title should be in lowercase.

I'm quoting from the *Chicago Manual of Style*, 13th ed.

> (Section 7.17) In text matter, titles following a personal name or used alone in place of a name are, with few exceptions, lowercased.

Without the doctor's name, you should say:

> They're ready for you now, doctor.

You are correct in your example of Doctor Watson.

> (Section 7.15) Civil, military, and *professional* titles and titles
>   of nobility are capitalized when they immediately precede a personal
>   name, as part of the name.

If you were to use the doctor's name, you should say:

> They're ready for you now, Doctor House.

Answer (score 1):

The *Chicago Manual of Style* has changed its preference in the 17th edition.

(Section 10.16) Abbreviations for social titles:

Thank you, Doctor

(I assume this goes for addressing a person as Doc, too)

Comment: Can you quote the acxonpanying paragraph, assuming there is one? This currently reads more as a comment to the accepted answer, but should be an up-to-date autonomous answer.